# Type error : "NoneType Object is not iterable" in python

Tags: python

'''Complete the given method called solve which takes as parameter a tuple A.

You have to return a new tuple with the first element and last 2 elements removed. A is guaranteed to be of at least 4 elements.

```
example input:
1 3 5 7
output:
3
```

## my code:

```
def solve(A):
    a= A[1:-1:2]
    print(*a,end=' ')
```

it shows an error like:

```
for i in A:
TypeError: 'NoneType'object is not iterable
```

Comment: your code actually works.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi but his code is wrong!

Comment: Your code is logically wrong according to the problem statement but your code indeed works with no error on the given input.

Comment: His code runs for a valid 4 length list and also gives the correct result. I'm wondering whrere the error is coming from. yes, his logic is wrong I agree.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi but 'A is guaranteed to be AT LEAST 4 elements', so it can be more than 4 elements, and in that case the code is not right

Comment: @CodeTalker for such trivial problems, you can't blame people, it takes 2-3 minutes to write a solution so many people answers at the same time. But, the point is there is no error in OP's code, so technically not sure why so many answers. For length 4, code works fine.

Comment: @JoãoCastilho for length 4, the code will give you the right answer but anyway it will fail for any length > 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
def solve(A):
    b = A[1:-2]
    # if you want to print just -> print(b)
    return b
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
def solve(A):
    a = A[1:-2]
    print(a,end=' ')
```

where 1 is the second index from left and -2 means the second index from the right. Keep in mind the element at index A[1] is inclusive while the element at -2 is exclusive.